# How can I change the output directory for typed-scss-modules?

Tags: typescript, sass

I use the typed-scss-modules library to generate TypeScript files based on my SASS files, mainly to obtain types returned with `:export{}`. However, I cannot find how to change the output paths in this library. By default, it generates *.d.ts files in the same folders as the targets.

[image]

Is there an option to specify the output folder? I would like to isolate TypeScript files in the `types/sass` folder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, according to [the documentation](https://github.com/skovy/typed-scss-modules#--outputfolder--o), there is an option to specify an output folder.